# gcc disable AMD64 bulldozer/piledriver instructions

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization, amd-processor

I need to compile a program targeting a specific architecture or better yet, compile using generic AMD64 instructions ignoring the more recent AMD cpu's (bulldozer and piledriver).

To be specific i need to absolutely ignore any FMA or XOP instructions (my understanding is that these are usually enabled during O2/3 optimizations.

I know that I can specify a specific cpu using --march or -mcpu, but where do I find these values, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: IIRC if you don't specify --march gcc plays it safe and just uses the AMD64 instructions understood by every processor.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not following, so I WANT O2/3 optimization except I want the compiler to ignore any FMA/XOP instructions. What are the compiler flags for that? $gcc -march=… ?

Comment: --mtune will create a binary that has a code path for the cpu type you specity, ie. k8-sse3, or core2, or whatever you specify, but, will also create a generic code path as a fallback for cpu's that do not understand certain instructions.

Comment: @janjust: what has march to do with -O2/-O3? If you don't specify -march, the compiler will still follow the indication to optimize given by -O, but will emit code that works on all AMD64 processors.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: if you specify O2/O3 optimizations the compiler will use certain instructions to optimize tight-loops, vector operations, etc. However if you specify an earlier target architecture my guess is that it will still perform the usual O2/O3 optimizations except it will not use the native arch. instructions (fma/xop). But anyways, the accepted answer solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html#i386-and-x86-64-Options) gives:

```
-mfma4
-mno-fma4
-mxop
-mno-xop
```

Obviously, depending on the age of your compiler, these may not be supported (but then the compiler won't generate the instructions either)

It is possible to achieve the same thing with `-march` or similar, but that is much coarser, and will probably turn of a bunch of other extensions/options.

Answer (score 2):

There is options for disabling and enabling specific instruction sets. They may be different in different gcc versions. My gcc 4.7 has following options to enable/disable FMA4 and XOP instruction sets:

```
-mfma4
-mno-fma4
-mxop
-mno-xop
```

as I know FMA3 was released after FMA4, and I think my version of gcc does not know about this instruction set.

Also gcc manual says:

While picking a specific cpu-type will schedule things appropriately for that particular chip, the compiler will not generate any code that does not run on the i386 without the -march=cpu-type option being used.

I think this means that if you don't specify -march option your code will run on your architecture correctly.